# Shopify Access a product with its id on thank you page without using '/admin' in url

Tags: javascript, json, shopify

I am trying to access a specific product using its id from the below url,

```
https://tempstore.myshopify.com/products/1234.json
```

Its giving me 404 error.
Although, I am able to access all products as below:

```
https://tempstore.myshopify.com/products.json
```

I have to access the product which was just processed in checkout process.
I have its id as below:

```
var products = Shopify.checkout.line_items;
```

**products** will contain an array of product id's only which are processed in checkout.
Now I need to access all other properties of these products.
I can surely do this:

```
https://tempstore.myshopify.com/admin/products/1234.json
```

But it requires Authentication.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

From the frontend, you need to have the product handle to get the JSON object:

```
https://tempstore.myshopify.com/products/[handle].js
```

or

```
https://tempstore.myshopify.com/products/[handle].json
```

(Note that the returned values from the `.js` and `.json` endpoints are quite different from each other!)

Like you point out, the Shopify.checkout.line_items array of objects only has the product IDs, *not* the product handles.  We're not completely out-of-luck, though, because we can get the entire list of products in the store including the product handles by hitting the `/products.json` endpoint.

Of course, this means grabbing a potentially huge JSON object just to get information that we should've had included in the checkout line items... but unless there's some alternate source of the line item information available on the checkout page, looping through the entire list may be what you need to do.

So your end code would look something like this:

```
Checkout.jQuery.getJSON(  // Or whatever your preferred way of getting info is
  'https://tempstore.myshopify.com/products.json',
  function(prodlist){
    for(var p = 0; p < prodlist.length; p++){
      var prod = prodlist[p];
      // Find if Shopify.checkout.line_items contains prod.id, left as exercise for the reader
      if(found){ 
        Checkout.jQuery.getJSON(
          'https://tempstore.myshopify.com/products/' + prod.handle + '.js', 
          function(product){ 
            /* Whatever needs to be done */
          })
      }
    }

  }

)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that, if you happen to be using Shopify Plus, you have the ability to do a lot more with your Checkout pages and would be able to get your information much more directly through Liquid info dumps in your checkout.liquid layout file

Comment: Yeah, I had to loop through.

Comment: What if we have 1000 products? As mobile phones have less processor and memory than other devices. Should we go with this approach?

Comment: Was away for a few days, sorry for the delay - in any case, grabbing a thousand products wouldn't be ideal for mobile, but you'd have to do some testing to find out what kind of an impact it would have.  At the very least, by getting the info asynchronously should prevent bottlenecks...

Comment: yeah. I relied on my own resources and made some shopify api requests. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var shop = Shopify.shop;
    var lineItems = Shopify.checkout.line_items;
        var url = 'https://' + shop + '/products.json?callback=?';
        var requiredData = [];
        $.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
            lineItems.forEach(function(lineItemProduct){
                data.products.find(function(product){
                   if(lineItemProduct.product_id == product.id){
                    requiredData.push(product);
                   }
                });
            });
        });

        console.log(requiredData);
```

This is how I solved it, If it helps anybody :)